# Does adding a constant preserve argmax?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, nonlinear-optimization

Is $argmax (f(x)) = argmax (f(x) + c)$?

This property is not listed in any of the argmax properties.
Intuitively this seems to be true as adding constant just shifts the graph upwards in the coordinate plane. This shouldn't change the corresponding 'x' value.

Comment: It might be helpful to include a citation for the mentioned list of "any of the argmax properties."  As you point out, the place where $f(x)$ is maximized is the same place where $f(x)+c$ is maximized (assuming $c$ constant).

Comment: https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Documents/2016_540_Argmax.pdf

Comment: In that case the property (albeit without your generous use of parentheses) is listed in Sec. 2 (Operations preserving *argmax*) as the first item.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, adding constant preserve it, suppose $x_1 \in \arg\max(f(x))$, then $$f(x_1) \ge f(x), \forall x \in X $$ hence

$$f(x_1)+c \ge f(x)+c, \forall x \in X $$

Hence $x_1 \in \arg\max (f(x)+c)$

the reverse direction is similar, we can subtract $c$ from both sides.